# Extract Noun Phrases with Stanza and CoreNLPClient

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, stanford-stanza

I am trying to extract noun phrases from sentences using Stanza(with Stanford CoreNLP). This can only be done with the CoreNLPClient module in Stanza.

```
# Import client module
from stanza.server import CoreNLPClient
# Construct a CoreNLPClient with some basic annotators, a memory allocation of 4GB, and port number 9001
client = CoreNLPClient(annotators=['tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','ner', 'parse'], memory='4G', endpoint='http://localhost:9001')
```

Here is an example of a sentence, and I am using the `tregrex` function in client to get all the noun phrases. `Tregex` function returns a `dict of dicts` in python. Thus I needed to process the output of the `tregrex` before passing it to the `Tree.fromstring` function in NLTK to correctly extract the Noun phrases as strings.

```
pattern = 'NP'
text = "Albert Einstein was a German-born theoretical physicist. He developed the theory of relativity."
matches = client.tregrex(text, pattern) ``
```

Hence, I came up with the method `stanza_phrases` which has to loop through the `dict of dicts` which is the output of `tregrex` and correctly format for `Tree.fromstring` in NLTK.

```
def stanza_phrases(matches):
  Nps = []
  for match in matches:
    for items in matches['sentences']:
      for keys,values in items.items():
        s = '(ROOT\n'+ values['match']+')'
        Nps.extend(extract_phrase(s, pattern))
  return set(Nps)
```

generates a tree to be used by NLTK

```
from nltk.tree import Tree
def extract_phrase(tree_str, label):
    phrases = []
    trees = Tree.fromstring(tree_str)
    for tree in trees:
        for subtree in tree.subtrees():
            if subtree.label() == label:
                t = subtree
                t = ' '.join(t.leaves())
                phrases.append(t)

    return phrases
```

Here is my output:

```
{'Albert Einstein', 'He', 'a German-born theoretical physicist', 'relativity',  'the theory', 'the theory of relativity'}
```

Is there a way I can make this more code efficient with less number of lines (especially, `stanza_phrases` and `extract_phrase` methods)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from stanza.server import CoreNLPClient

# get noun phrases with tregex
def noun_phrases(_client, _text, _annotators=None):
    pattern = 'NP'
    matches = _client.tregex(_text,pattern,annotators=_annotators)
    print("\n".join(["\t"+sentence[match_id]['spanString'] for sentence in matches['sentences'] for match_id in sentence]))

# English example
with CoreNLPClient(timeout=30000, memory='16G') as client:
    englishText = "Albert Einstein was a German-born theoretical physicist. He developed the theory of relativity."
    print('---')
    print(englishText)
    noun_phrases(client,englishText,_annotators="tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse")

# French example
with CoreNLPClient(properties='french', timeout=30000, memory='16G') as client:
    frenchText = "Je suis John."
    print('---')
    print(frenchText)
    noun_phrases(client,frenchText,_annotators="tokenize,ssplit,mwt,pos,lemma,parse")
```

Comment: This should work with Stanford CoreNLP 4.0.0 and stanza 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The [Constituent-Treelib](https://github.com/Halvani/Constituent-Treelib) does exactly what you want to accomplish, and with very few lines of code.

First install it via: `pip install constituent-treelib`

Then, perform the following steps:

```py
import spacy
from constituent_treelib import ConstituentTree

text = "Albert Einstein was a German-born theoretical physicist. He developed the theory of relativity."
nlp_pipeline = ConstituentTree.create_pipeline(ConstituentTree.Language.English)
doc = nlp_pipeline(text)
extracted_phrases = []

for sent in doc.sents:
    sentence = sent.text    
    tree = ConstituentTree(sentence, nlp_pipeline)
    extracted_phrases.append(tree.extract_all_phrases())

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Output of extracted_phrases:

[{'S': ['Albert Einstein was a German - born theoretical physicist .'],
  'ADJP': ['German - born'],
  'VP': ['was a German - born theoretical physicist'],
  'NP': ['Albert Einstein', 'a German - born theoretical physicist']},
 {'S': ['He developed the theory of relativity .'],
  'PP': ['of relativity'],
  'VP': ['developed the theory of relativity'],
  'NP': ['the theory of relativity', 'the theory']}]
```